# Postman - access full request body (to calculate hash) in pre-request script

Tags: javascript, c#, security, postman

I'm trying to recreate C# DelegatingHandler inside PostMan.
I've created pre-request script that calculates auth header value.

Currently my script looks like this:

```
function S4() {
    return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1); 
}

function GetNonce() {
    return (S4() + S4() + S4()+ S4() + S4() + S4() + S4()+ S4()).toLowerCase();
}

function GetTimeStamp() {
    var d = new Date();
    return Math.round(d.getTime() / 1000);
}

function getAuthHeader(httpMethod, requestUrl, requestBody) {
    var CLIENT_KEY = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('hmac_user');
    var SECRET_KEY = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('hmac_key');
    var AUTH_TYPE = 'HMAC';

    requestUrl = requestUrl.replace(/{{(\w*)}}/g,function(str,key) {return environment[key]});
    requestUrl = requestUrl.toLowerCase();
    var requestTimeStamp = GetTimeStamp();
    var nonce = GetNonce();
    var bodyHash="";

    if (httpMethod == 'GET' || !requestBody) {
        requestBody = ''; 
    } else {
        var md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(requestBody);
        bodyHash = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(md5);
    }  

    var signatureRawData = [CLIENT_KEY, requestUrl, httpMethod, requestTimeStamp, nonce, bodyHash].join("");

    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(SECRET_KEY);
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(signatureRawData, key);
    var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

    var header = [CLIENT_KEY, hashInBase64, nonce, requestTimeStamp].join(":");

    return AUTH_TYPE+" "+header;
}

postman.setEnvironmentVariable('hmacAuthHeader', getAuthHeader(request.method, request.url, request.data));
```

This works perfect for GET requests that don't have any body. However when I send `x-www-form-urlencoded` request I get unauthorized response (401), because of body hash differences inside C# and Postman.

Inside Postman `request.data` is a JSON object, but when I investigate request in Fiddler I see it is send as string (see below screenshot)
[image]

Same thing happens when I send `form-data`. Inside Postman I've added 3 fields, one with string value, two with files. In Fiddler I can see full request, but inside Postman I can't access those files (see below screenshot) 
[image]

I'm trying to access full request body, because I need to calculate hash out of it.

I have working code in C#, not I want to recreate same requests with Postman.

My question is:
**How can I access full request body in pre-request script?**

I use this code in C# and it works fine:

```
internal class HmacClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly string _applicationId;
    private readonly string _applicationKey;

    public HmacClientHandler(string appId, string appKey)
    {
        _applicationId = appId;
        _applicationKey = appKey;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage>SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        string url = Uri.EscapeUriString(request.RequestUri.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        string methodName = request.Method.Method;

        DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;
        string requestTimeStamp = Convert.ToUInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        string nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

        string contentBase64String = string.Empty;

        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            byte[] content = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(content);
            contentBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }

        string authenticationKeyString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", _applicationId, url, methodName, requestTimeStamp, nonce, contentBase64String);
        var secretKeyBase64ByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(_applicationKey);

        using (HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(secretKeyBase64ByteArray))
        {
            byte[] authenticationKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authenticationKeyString);
            byte[] authenticationHash = hmac.ComputeHash(authenticationKeyBytes);
            string hashedBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(authenticationHash);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("HMAC", string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", _applicationId, hashedBase64String, nonce, requestTimeStamp));
        }

        response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it's just not possible (not supported): https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1050

Comment: @Evk thanks for finding this. Sadly I will have to find alternative :/

Comment: @Evk internally Postman calculates hashes from body: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-request/blob/master/lib/oauth.js#L64 but this isn't available from pre-request scripts.

Comment: Well your hash function is SHA512, and source code by link suggests that it only calculates SHA1 anyway.

Comment: @Evk hash function doesn't matter-I can change it. My main problem is that I can't access request body in pre-request script.

Answer (score 5):

The previously quoted issue (#1050) appears to only apply to the request body in binary/file mode (`RequestBody.MODES.file`).  The `RequestBody` API provides what I need for a similar use case:  https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/RequestBody.html

I believe that if you reference `pm.request.body` in your pre-request script, it will provide what you're looking for.  Specifically, `pm.request.body.toString()` appears to provide the actual `x-www-url-encoded` string that will ultimately appear in the request (although, if you use *environment variables* in your request parameters, these will be emitted unresolved, e.g., `{{variable_name}}`).

So for your script above, I changed the last line to:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('hmacAuthHeader', getAuthHeader(request.method, request.url, pm.request.body.toString()));
```

... and that seems to provide a plausible HMAC.  Be sure to pay attention to all of the rules for your hash/HMAC protocol, including sorting of parameters, whitespace handling, etc.

Also, I'm not certain that the `RequestBody` API is available in all incarnations of Postman, but works swimmingly on my native Windows and OS X editions.  Hope this helps!